# Why is IE not unselecting option with $(element).val('');?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Although other browsers seems fine, IE7 is not friendly with my 10 lines javascript.

All the (small) code can be found here : **http://jsfiddle.net/7nGd9/**

```
$(function() {
    $('#prepareSpecificProgressModal')
        .each(function(index, modal) {
            var
                modal = $(modal),
                form  = $('#myform');

            form.on('change', 'select', function(){
                 var node = $(this);
                    node
                        .closest('form')
                        .find('select').not(this)
                        .each(function(i, element){
                             element.selectedIndex = -1;
                        });
            });
        });
});
```

I'm using `$(element).val('');` to reset the selection of option but it's not working under IE7. Basically it allows multiple selection across the 3 select even if there are JS supposed to prevent it.

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: You should use `.prop()` to get the "id" value, not `.attr()` - I don't know for sure that that's the problem however.

Comment: Your code should be, `node.closest('form').find('select').not(this).val('');`

Comment: @Pointy: Should be no difference, afaik the `id` prop is reflective (though it might be faster).

Comment: Please post your code *into* the question. The question should be able to stand on its own without an outside link.

Comment: @Bergi old versions of IE will not return element properties from calls to `getAttribute()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
.each(function(i, element) {
    element.selectedIndex = -1;
})
```

to unselect all options ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7nGd9/2/)). Or, instead of the `each` loop, you can use `.prop("selectedIndex", -1)` equivalently (would have worked with `.val('')`, too).

Btw, according to the [docs of `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), you can pass an array of the options to select (or `null` instead of the empty array):

```
.val([]);
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7nGd9/4/))

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the value of the `select`, you can select all the options and change the `prop` to `false` with:

```
.find('select[id!='+node.attr('id')+'] option').prop('selected', false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9NPf5/

..or do both with:

```
.find('select[id!='+node.attr('id')+'] option').prop('selected', false).parent().val('');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n3jCs/

Comment: Please post the answer *into* the answer. If the JSFiddle link dies or moves, this answer becomes useless for a future visitor.